# Numpy rolling window calculation

Tags: python, numpy, gis, arcgis, ca

I am really new to python and numpy so please bear with me.

I am trying to create a cellular automata for hydrological purposes, more specifically flood modelling.I have 2 rasters, a DEM and a raster with water levels. With those two rasters I want to find the lowest elevation in a 3x3 neighborhood and then calculate the water flow between the center cell and the lowest cell.

I could not find any way of doing this in arcgis and the datasets are quite large so numpy arrays seem to be my best bet. So far I have transformed both rasters to numpy arrays and created a rolling window that goes through each cell of the array. The window was created using the slide trick(http://arogozhnikov.github.io/2015/09/30/NumpyTipsAndTricks2.html). I know that I can get the index of the minimum value using argmin, but i dont know how to combine it with the second array.

What I would like to do is create the rolling window so that it goes trough both arrays at the same time and using the index of the lowest height in the neighborhood calculate the water flow between the lowest cell and the center cell. After calculating the water flow the transition rules would be an if/else statement based on whether the water flow is bigger that the water level or not. All of this needs to be done inside the rolling window and I'm not sure about how to do that

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is the code i'm working with now:

```
import arcpy
import datetime
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

#Set environment and date variables to import DEM and Runnoff rasters
current_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=n)
date = str(current_date)
env.workspace = "Esri Geodatabase"
inDEM = "DEM"
inRaster = "C:/.../Q_" + date.replace("-    ", "_") + ".tif"
outRaster = "C:/Esri.gdb/test"

#Retrieve raster properties for later export
dsc=arcpy.Describe(inRaster)
sr=dsc.SpatialReference
ext=dsc.Extent
ll=arcpy.Point(ext.XMin,ext.YMin)

#Import Runnoff and DEM as numpy arrays
Water_level = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(inRaster)
DEM = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(inDEM, nodata_to_value=3000)

#Create rolling window 
def rolling_window(array, window_size):
    itemsize = array.itemsize
    shape = (array.shape[0] - window_size + 1,
             array.shape[1] - window_size + 1,
             window_size, window_size)
    strides = (array.shape[1] * itemsize, itemsize,
               array.shape[1] * itemsize, itemsize)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(array, shape=shape, strides=strides)
```

I use timedelta because after i make this work i will loop it for an N number of days in the future. I also assign 3000 to no data value because all the DEM values are bellow 2300 and this way the nodata will not interfere. The DEM shape is really irregular so if there is a way to mask the nodata values it would be great.

Initially the rolling window didn't use the stride trick and i was using it to loop through the file like this:

```
for x, i in enumerate(window, 1):
    for y, j in enumerate(i, 1):
```

The reason why I gave up on this approach is that its already quite slow,with the arrays being around 3500x3500, and when I would add the zip function to use both arrays it would be even more so.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I know this isn't easy since you have a lot of data, but could you try to make a small example? See [MCVE].

Comment: I edited my question to include some of the code I am using and my previous approach to it which was very slow so I gave up/

Comment: The [Flow Direction](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#/Flow_Direction/009z00000052000000/) and [Flow Accumulation](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#/Flow_Accumulation/009z00000051000000/) tools in ArcMap are usually what's used for hydrology analysis.

Comment: @Erica:the Flow Accumulation tool in ArcMap is not enough for my purposes. It only calculates the number of cells that flow into that specific cell. What I want to do is calculate the amount of water in the cell and if the water volume has a height big enough for the water to overflow into an adjoining cell do that. I have looked into a tool that does that but i could not find anything, so if you know of a way to do that, please let me know.

Comment: The water is always going to be flowing into the lowest cell in the 3x3 window, unless you aren't eliminating "sinks" in the raster before beginning processing (and once the water starts accumulating, it's going to be a constant height throughout that 3x3 window, not overflowing anywhere). I'm certainly not saying that you must use the existing ArcMap tools if it just won't work for your model (they aren't perfect) and I honestly don't have much solution to your specific code question -- just thought I'd throw it out there :)

Comment: @Erica: I appreciate your answer, but flow accumulation is not enough for what I want to achieve. The DEM has been prepared, with all sinks removed. I know that Flow Accumulation uses the lowest cell, but it allows any amount of water to flow trough that cell. I have edited my question to specify that the purpose is flood modelling, which this tool is not capable of helping with. Thank you again for trying to help me.